# Classe não encontrada no composer e phpunit

Tags: php, classes, composer, phpunit

classe ProductStructureTeste não encontra classe ProductStructure.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

 use App\ProductStructure;
 use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;


 class ProductStructureTest extends TestCase
 {
private ProductStructure $productStructure;

protected function setUp(): void
{
    $this->productStructure = new ProductStructure();
}
```

E a classe Product Structure

```
<?php
namespace App;

 class ProductStructure
  {
const products = [
    "preto-PP",
   
];

public function make(): array
{
    return [];
}
}
```

O retorno do terminal:

```
 1) ProductStructureTest::testMake
 Error: Class "App\ProductStructure" not found

 D:\xampp\htdocs\teste-logica-main\test\ProductStructureTest.php:15

  ERRORS!
  Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

Composer.json

```
 {
   "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
       "App\\": "src/"
     }
    },
   "require": {
    "php": "^8.1"
    },
   "require-dev": {
     "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"
    }
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Olá, você poderia prover mais informações sobre o seu ambiente? Como a configuração do composer, a configuração do phpunit e quais seriam os erros que você recebe no terminal? Obrigado.

Comment: No arquivo do composer.json tem as seguintes informações:                                   
 "php": "^8.1"    e        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"

Comment: Poderia editar sua pergunta com todos esses arquivos (não precisa colocar nada que exponha as regras de negócio do projeto, mas só o composer.json e a config do phpunit)? Assim reproduzir o bug, se necessário e entender melhor a estrutura do projeto em si.

Comment: O composer.json já coloquei ai. O phpunit vc quer as linhas do arquivo?

Comment: O erro da linha 15 é esse:        $this->productStructure = new ProductStructure();
Porque ele não encontra a classe

Comment: PHPUnit 9.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Answer (score 0):

### Motivo

Olá, aparentemente o erro está ocorrendo por conta do seu Composer não conseguir encontrar a classe `App\ProductStructure`, pois a mesma não se encontra nos padrões do `psr-4 autoloading` do PHP.

Caso você queira ver essa mensagem, execute no seu terminal o comando `composer dump-autoload -o` que ele irá mostrar a seguinte mensagem:

```sh
Class App\ProductStructure located in ./src/productStructure.php
does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
```

Quando isso ocorre, quer dizer que o composer não irá realizar o `require` deste arquivo no ambiente de execução do composer e o phpunit, o qual pertence a este ambiente criado pelo composer, também não irá reconhecê-lo.

### Reprodução

Consegui reproduzir parcialmente (dado que não tenho todas as configurações e comandos que você realizou no seu projeto) no [REPL.it](https://replit.com/@aleDsz/php-composer-test) caso queira entender o que pode estar faltando no seu projeto para que ele consiga executar o `phpunit`.

[image: Execução do phpunit]

Answer (score -1):

composer dump-autoload -o

```
 Generating optimized autoload files
 Generated optimized autoload files containing 1099 classes
```

composer test

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
 Command "test" is not defined.
```

E continua o mesmo erro. Basicamente o projeto so tem essas duas classes que eu postei acima.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: O erro do comando é pq eu defini um `script` na mesma vibe que o `npm` faz no `package.json`

Comment: pois tá muito difícil isso....